# JavaFX showing view make in scene builder with controller

Tags: java, model-view-controller, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I have this controller:

```
package cz.vutbr.feec.bmds.cv2;

import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.TextField;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;

public class TestGuiController {

    private int buttonPressed = 0;
    @FXML
    private Button tlacitko;
    @FXML
    private TextField textovePole;
    @FXML
    private Slider slider;

    public void buttonPressed(ActionEvent e) {
        buttonPressed++;
        textovePole.setText(Integer.toString(buttonPressed));
    }
}
```

this fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>

    <AnchorPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="cz.vutbr.feec.bmds.cv2.TestGuiController">
      <children>
        <Button fx:id="tlacitko" layoutX="30.0" layoutY="40.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onTouchPressed="#buttonPressed" text="Button" />
        <Slider fx:id="slider" layoutX="157.0" layoutY="17.0" orientation="VERTICAL" />
        <TextField fx:id="textovePole" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="89.0" prefWidth="134.0" />
      </children>
    </AnchorPane>
```

and this is my main class:

```
package cz.vutbr.feec.bmds.cv2;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("TestGui.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Titulek");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root,300,275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

When I run this through ant I get message box with error (exception during running application). I tried simple fxml without controller and it works so I am guesing I do something wrong with controller. What I must change to have it working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I must answer my own question. Problem was in `TestGuiController` where I used `java.awt.Button` and `java.awt.TextField` instead of `javafx.scene.control.Button` and `javafx.scene.control.TextField`.

Comment: Yeah! Finally I got my problem solved! Thank you for posting your solution here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but try:

- in FXML: Button: onAction instead of onTouchPressed

Please provide the exact Exception message.

Comment: I was seeing just error which I wrote but when I add code for showing error message then It was clear. I was using awt button and awt TextField instead of javafx. Thanks for help